# How to Bind an XmlDataProvider Class Property to a XAML TreeView

Tags: c#, data-binding, xaml, xmldataprovider

I would like to bind a TreeView control I have defined in XAML to a property in its code-behind class. I already read through a [WPF Basic Data Binding FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx), but the example in the comments at the very bottom of the page didn't work when I tried to use an XmlDataProvider as the binding source.

How can I modify the following code so that the binding is defined in the XAML, rather than in the class's constructor? In other words, how can I modify the TreeView's `ItemsSource` attribute to reference a property in its code-behind class?

#### SomeClass.xaml - Works

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeNamespace.SomeClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="SomeTreeData" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <TreeView Name="SomeTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeTreeData}, XPath=*}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="items" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Header}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="item" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Header}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```

#### SomeClass.xaml.cs - Works

```
public partial class SomeClass : UserControl
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        XmlDataProvider lSomeTreeData
            = this.FindResource("SomeTreeData") as XmlDataProvider;
        lSomeTreeData.Document = new XmlDocument();
        lSomeTreeData.Document.LoadXml("<items xmlns=\"\" Header=\"Some items\"><item Header=\"Some item\" /></items>");
    }
}
```

#### SomeClass.xaml - Desired

Note the `{SOME MAGIC}` in the TreeView's `ItemsSource` attribute.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeNamespace.SomeClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TreeView Name="SomeTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={SOME MAGIC}, XPath=*}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="items" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Header}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="item" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Header}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```

#### SomeClass.xaml.cs - Desired

```
public partial class SomeClass : UserControl
{
    public XmlDataProvider SomeXmlDataProvider { get; set; }

    public SomeClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SomeXmlDataProvider = new XmlDataProvider();
        this.SomeXmlDataProvider.Document = new XmlDocument();
        this.SomeXmlDataProvider.Document.LoadXml("<items xmlns=\"\" Header=\"Some items\"><item Header=\"Some item\" /></items>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that one option is to set the control's `DataContext`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeNamespace.SomeClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/items}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="items" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Header}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="item" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Header}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```

---

```
public partial class SomeClass : UserControl
{
    public XmlDataProvider SomeXmlDataProvider { get; set; }

    public SomeClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SomeXmlDataProvider = new XmlDataProvider();
        this.SomeXmlDataProvider.Document = new XmlDocument();
        this.SomeXmlDataProvider.Document.LoadXml("<items Header=\"Some items\"><item Header=\"Some item\" /></items>");

        this.DataContext = this.SomeXmlDataProvider.Document;
    }
}
```